# Return opening hours, past midnight

Tags: php

I have opening and closing times stored in my MySQL Database like below:

```
opening_time_Sunday  10:30
closing_time_Sunday  00:00
opening_time_Monday  09:30
closing_time_Monday  01:30
opening_time_Tuesday  09:30
closing_time_Tuesday  01:30
opening_time_Wednesday  09:30
closing_time_Wednesday  01:30
opening_time_Thursday  09:30
closing_time_Thursday  01:30
opening_time_Friday  09:30
closing_time_Friday  23:00
opening_time_Saturday  10:30
closing_time_Saturday  00:00
```

The issue I'm having is when trying to display the stores opening and closing times, on say Monday, if it passes midnight it starts reading Tuesdays time and shows that the shop is closed, even though it's meant to stay open until 01:30am.

I understand why this is happening, but not sure what logic to use to make it read (for e.g.) Monday up until the closing date, this is my current function:

```
public static function setting($setting)
{
    $config = Settings::where('setting', $setting)->first();
    if ($config) {
        return $config->value;
    }
}

public static function Today() {
    $today = date('l');
    $start      = self::setting('opening_time_' . $today); // Select value from settings table
    $end        = self::setting('closing_time_' . $today); // Select value from settings table
    return $start . " - " . $end;
}
```

Comment: Please, post setting method as well

Comment: You need to show the code you are using to set the closing_time_Monday, showing the calling method alone does not offer any clues.

Comment: So `closing_time_Monday` is 1:30 on Tuesday? Then it's not really a monday-closing-time in the strict sense. My first thought would be that you could either put the times to the correct weekdays, or you need some way to determine that the saved time is really on the next day (like comparing closing time to opening time, or simply a flag).

Comment: I have added the setting function, it returns the values from the table.

Comment: @Karsten Koop that's right, it overlaps to Tuesday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To dynamically determine which date of times to display, you would need to perform a process of elimination on the closing time of the prior date, by checking if today's closing date is greater than the current time.

However since the day of the week is not included in the close time, you also have to verify that the close time is `am` to avoid false positives.

### Dynamic Example: https://3v4l.org/Cs6jS

```
public static function Today() {
    $currentDate = new \DateTimeImmutable;
    $priorDate = $currentDate->sub(new \DateTimeInterval('P1D'));
    $yesterday = $priorDate->format('l');

    $priorClosing = self::setting('closing_time_' . $yesterday);
    $closeDate = $currentDate->setTime(...explode(':', $priorClosing));

    if ($closeDate->format('a') === 'am' && $currentDate < $closeDate) {
        //check if the closing has not occurred yet
        $currentDate = $priorDate;
    }

    $today = $currentDate->format('l');
    $start = self::setting('opening_time_' . $today);
    $end = self::setting('closing_time_' . $today);

    return $start . " - " . $end;
}
```

**Results:**

```
Day         |   00:15:00                    |   23:00:00
Monday      |   Monday: 09:30 - 01:30       |   Monday: 09:30 - 01:30
Tuesday     |   Monday: 09:30 - 01:30       |   Tuesday: 09:30 - 01:30
Wednesday   |   Tuesday: 09:30 - 01:30      |   Wednesday: 09:30 - 01:30
Thursday    |   Wednesday: 09:30 - 01:30    |   Thursday: 09:30 - 01:30
Friday      |   Thursday: 09:30 - 01:30     |   Friday: 09:30 - 23:00
Saturday    |   Saturday: 10:30 - 00:00     |   Saturday: 10:30 - 00:00
Sunday      |   Sunday: 10:30 - 00:00       |   Sunday: 10:30 - 00:00
```

*(same for each method, but results will vary based on opening closing dates used)*

> With your current hours of operation structure, the above example will provide a false positive when the hours for the open and close dates are both `AM`.
>   The only way to avoid this is to include the day of the week in the opening and closing times of a given day.

---

### Comparative Example: https://3v4l.org/q57eD

*(most accurate - if operation duration does not exceed 24 hours)*

To resolve the issue with false positives with the previous day starting and closing in the `AM`. The issue being that a day of closing is not known and assuming the operation duration is always less than 24 hours. You would also compare the opening time of the prior date with the closing date and ensure they do not exceed 24 hours.

```
public static function Today() {
    $currentDate = new \DateTimeImmutable;
    $priorDate = $currentDate->sub(new \DateTimeInterval('P1D'));
    $yesterday = $priorDate->format('l');

    $priorOpening = self::setting('opening_time_' . $yesterday);
    $priorClosing = self::setting('closing_time_' . $yesterday);

    $priorOpenDate = $priorDate->setTime(...explode(':', $priorOpening));
    $closeDate = $currentDate->setTime(...explode(':', $priorClosing));
    $diff = $priorOpenDate->diff($closeDate);

    if ($diff->d === 0 && $currentDate < $closeDate) {
        //check if the closing has not occurred yet
        $currentDate = $priorDate;
    }

    $today = $currentDate->format('l');
    $start = self::setting('opening_time_' . $today);
    $end = self::setting('closing_time_' . $today);

    return $start . " - " . $end;
}
```

---

Alternatively since only `Mon-Thur` are open past midnight, you can hard-code the days to check and determine which day to select based on the current time.

This example only checks if the current day is `Tues-Fri` and when the current time has not reached `01:30`, then changes `today` to `yesterday`.

### Hard-coded Example: https://3v4l.org/Vtr6L

```
public static function Today() {
    $currentDate = new \DateTimeImmutable;
    if (in_array($currentDate->format('N'), [2, 3, 4, 5])) {              
        //check current time is not beyond the threshold
        $closedDate = $currentDate->setTime(1, 30, 00);
        if ($currentDate < $closedDate) {
            //change the date to display to day prior
            $currentDate = $currentDate->sub(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
        }
    }
    $today = $currentDate->format('l');

    $start      = self::setting('opening_time_' . $today); // Select value from settings table
    $end        = self::setting('closing_time_' . $today); // Select value from settings table
    return $start . " - " . $end;
}
```